# How can I convert a azure function to a regular python script?

Tags: python, azure-functions

I am very new to python & I have encountered a problem which is: I have to convert an azure function code to a normal python script. I did not work with azure before so I am kind of clueless. Here is the code below,

this is a process to analyze a document  and return key-value pairs, but I am not aware how to convert this code into a regular python script & run it locally.

```
import logging

from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
import json
import re
import uuid

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
import azure.functions as func

def upload_blob(account_name, container_name, account_key, blob_name):
    # Create the BlockBlobService that is used to call the Blob service for the storage account
    blob_service_client = BlockBlobService(
        account_name=account_name,
        account_key=account_key)
    # Set the permission so the blobs are public.
    blob_service_client.set_container_acl(container_name, public_access=PublicAccess.Container)
    #blob_name = doc_path.split('/')[-1][:-4] + str(uuid.uuid4()) + ".pdf"
    # Upload the created file, use blob_name for the blob name
    #blob_service_client.create_blob_from_path(container_name, blob_name, doc_path)
    blob_url = blob_service_client.make_blob_url(container_name, blob_name)
    return blob_url

def delete_blob(account_name, container_name, account_key, blob_name):
    blob_service_client = BlockBlobService(
        account_name=account_name,
        account_key=account_key)
    # Delete blob from container
    blob_service_client.delete_blob(container_name, blob_name)

def search_value(kvs, search_key):
    for key, value in kvs.items():
        if re.search(search_key, key, re.IGNORECASE):
            return value

def analyze_general_documents(endpoint, api_key, doc_url):
    document_analysis_client = DocumentAnalysisClient(
        endpoint=endpoint, credential=AzureKeyCredential(api_key)
    )
    poller = document_analysis_client.begin_analyze_document_from_url("prebuilt-document", doc_url)
    result = poller.result()
    #print("----Key-value pairs found in document----")
    kvs = {}
    content = result.content.replace("\n", "").replace("\r", "").strip()
    for kv_pair in result.key_value_pairs:
        if kv_pair.key:
            key = kv_pair.key.content
            if kv_pair.value:
                val = kv_pair.value.content
                kvs[key] = val
    return content, kvs

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    try:
        # Query parameters
        endpoint = ""
        api_key = ""
        account_name = ""
        container_name = ""
        account_key = ""
        
        if "blob_name" in req.get_json() and "search_keys" in req.get_json():
            blob_name = req.get_json()["blob_name"]
            search_keys = req.get_json()["search_keys"]

            logger.info(" search_keys = "+str(search_keys))

            # Upload file to Azure Storage container.
            logger.info("Creating blob url")
            blob_url = upload_blob(account_name, container_name, account_key, blob_name)
            #logger.info("Blob url = "+str(blob_url))

            # Analyze the document
            content, kvs = analyze_general_documents(endpoint, api_key, blob_url)
            #logger.info("content = "+content)
            #logger.info("kvs = "+str(kvs))

            # Search for specified keys
            search_results = {}
            for search_key in search_keys:
                val = search_value(kvs, search_key)
                if val:
                    search_results[search_key] = val
            #logger.info("search_results = "+str(search_results))

            # Delete the uploaded file
            delete_blob(account_name, container_name, account_key, blob_name)

            # Return search results
            return func.HttpResponse(json.dumps(search_results))
        else:
            return func.HttpResponse("Please pass in end_point, api_key, and blob_name", status_code=400)
    except Exception as e:
        return func.HttpResponse("Error: " + str(e), status_code=500)
```

Comment: Hey, welcome to SO.. kindly don't add credential at public forum.. remove it at best

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First things first - this may not be the full solution to your problem but maybe helps you with deriving next steps. The script should be re-coded imho since it is based on an old library that might not be maintained any more. However, below are some ideas; this is by no means a real solution and must not be used with production data.

Your imported libraries can remain as-is. Just note that when you install the libraries through `pip install {library_name}`, you would need to use the old `azure-storage` library and not `azure-storage-blob`, since this one won't have the `BlockBlobService`.

Also, if you want to run the script from the command-line, you might want to pass the parameters that the function originally receives through the HTTP request. For this purpose you could use `argparse`. Furthermore, you might not want to use the credentials within your script file but rather export them as environment variables - then you would need the `os` library as well.

That said, your imports would look like this:

```py
import logging

from azure.ai.formrecognizer import DocumentAnalysisClient
from azure.core.credentials import AzureKeyCredential
from azure.storage.blob import BlockBlobService, PublicAccess
import json
import re
import uuid

# Importing argparse for being able to pass parameters
import argparse

# Importing os to read environment variables
import os
```

You would not need `import azure.functions as func` any more.

Because it is running locally, you *could* pass the parameters `blobname` and `searchkeys` when executing the script. This would require something like this:

```py
parser = argparse.ArgumentParser()
parser.add_argument("-n", "--blobname", type=str)
parser.add_argument("-s", "--searchkeys", type=str)

args = parser.parse_args()

blob_name = args.blobname
search_keys = args.searchkeys
```

This would allow you to keep the variable names as they are right now.
Like initially mentioned, the functions can remain as-is, however, the credentials should not be within the script. With `os` imported, you could add this...

```
# Query parameters
endpoint = os.getenv('form_recognizer_endpoint')
api_key = os.getenv('form_recognizer_api_key')
account_name = os.getenv('storage_account_name')
container_name = os.getenv('storage_container_name')
account_key = os.getenv('storage_account_key')
```

...and then use the `export` functionality from your shell to add them as environment variables, i.E.:

```bash
export form_recognizer_endpoint="your_endpoint"
export form_recognizer_api_key="your_api_key"
export storage_account_name="your_account_name"
export storage_container_name="your_container"
export storage_account_key="your_key"
```

Finally, you could remove the surrounding `def main` and the `try-except` block and also the if-statement so that your main block would be along these lines:

```
logger.info(" search_keys = "+str(search_keys))

# Upload file to Azure Storage container.
logger.info("Creating blob url")
blob_url = upload_blob(account_name, container_name, account_key, blob_name)
#logger.info("Blob url = "+str(blob_url))

# Analyze the document
content, kvs = analyze_general_documents(endpoint, api_key, blob_url)
#logger.info("content = "+content)
#logger.info("kvs = "+str(kvs))

# Search for specified keys
search_results = {}
for search_key in search_keys:
    val = search_value(kvs, search_key)
    if val:
        search_results[search_key] = val
#logger.info("search_results = "+str(search_results))
# Delete the uploaded file
delete_blob(account_name, container_name, account_key, blob_name)
```

Finally you could change the return line to print out the result, i.E.:

```
# Return search results
print(json.dumps(search_results))
```

It could be executed like this: `python script.py --blobname testfile.pdf --searchkeys "text"`